# Calculating Sum of 2 Vectors using Laws of Cosine

Tags: vectors

I found this to calculate the sum of 2 vectors with a specific angle $v$:

It's the law of cosine: $$a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(v)$$

Sources are split on this, however ...

One source says  the one above is the way to go, but others say this one is:

$$a^2 + b^2 +2ab\cos(v) $$

(the same but with + and + instead of + and -)

Could someone please shed a light on this?

Comment: This at most gives the *length* of the sum, provided you denote with $a$ and $b$ the length of the given vectors. The correct version is the one with $-$.

Comment: `Sources are split` Math is not a popularity contest. Try to derive the formula yourself (think law of cosines), and if you get stuck then *that* would be an appropriate question to ask here.

Comment: You  can see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491875/proof-of-vector-addition-formula

Comment: @egreg The $+$ formula is correct when $v$ is the actual angle between vectors. The $-$ formula probably comes from a context where one defines $a = \vec{BC}, b = \vec{CA}, v = \widehat {BCA}$. However, in that case $v$ is not the angle between the two vectors, but rather its supplement.

Comment: As a now disappeared comment said, it depends on how you measure the angle between the vectors; draw the parallelogram and you'll instantly find the required angle and the correct law of cosine to apply.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ambiguity here which I think comes from the way
we define the "angle" that is used in the formula.

Consider this visualization of vector addition, copied from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Addition.svg:

[image]

To find the length of $\mathbf a + \mathbf b$, we can apply the
Law of Cosines to one of the two triangles with sides 
$\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$, and $\mathbf a + \mathbf b$.
Either triangle is OK since they are congruent.
The Law of Cosines tells us that
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \phi
$$
where $a = \|\mathbf a\|$, $b = \|\mathbf b\|$, 
$c = \|\mathbf a + \mathbf b\|$,
and $\phi$ is the angle of the sides $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ of the triangle.
Depending on which of the two triangles you choose, this is
either the angle where the head of a copy of $\mathbf a$
meets the tail of a copy of $\mathbf b$
or the angle where the head of a copy of $\mathbf b$
meets the tail of a copy of $\mathbf a$.
In other words, to use this formula we should set $\phi$ to one of the
"head-to-tail" angles in the figure.

But when we measure the angle between two vectors, it is more usual
to measure the "tail-to-tail" angle, that is, the angle
in the figure where the tail of a copy of $\mathbf a$
and the tail of a copy of $\mathbf b$ coincide
(which is also the point where the tail of $\mathbf a + \mathbf b$
is drawn in the figure).

Let's write $\alpha$ to denote the "tail-to-tail" angle between the vectors.
Since the copies of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$
in the figure above form a parallelogram, we know that
$$
\alpha = \pi - \phi
$$
(measured in radians)
and therefore
$$
\cos(\alpha) = -cos(\phi).
$$
Therefore the Law of Cosines actually tells us that
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos \alpha.
$$

In other words, whether you have "$+\cos\theta$" or "$-\cos\theta$"
is entirely due to whether you define $\theta$ the way $\phi$
is defined above or the way $\alpha$ is defined above.

The answer  [Proof of vector addition formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491875/proof-of-vector-addition-formula)
comes to this conclusion as well, but the figure that supports that answer 
seems to have been lost.

Comment: Since this is basically just a reiteration of arguments already made on MSE, only supplying a missing figure, I've made it a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the angle $v$ is between the two vectors taken ''tail to tail'' or ''head to tail''. This two angles are supplementary. You can  see this answer: [Proof of vector addition formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491875/proof-of-vector-addition-formula)